# iSCSI initiator - only want one of three available volumes

Tags: centos, iscsi

Initiator: CentOS 6.4
Target: EqualLogic PS6110

I have three volumes currently exported from this SAN. I want to connect to one of these (and only one) from the CentOS machine.

What I've tried:

```
iscsiadm -m node -l -T <iscsi target of interest> -l -p 10.10.27.100:3260
```

This gives me `/dev/sd1` (after the volume is partitioned, labeled and formatted).

```
mount /dev/sd1 /u1
```

gives me a working volume. All is well!

Except after I reboot I get all three volumes from the SAN available as /dev/sdd, sde, sdf and sdf1. As the other two volumes on this system are used for Xen HA I *really really* don't want to mess with them.

How do I keep the initiator from being so friendly with the SAN?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the 'extra' targets from reappearing by going to `/var/lib/iscsi/nodes` and deleting the unwanted connections. Also go to `/var/lib/iscsi/send_targets/` and removing the links to same.

Comment: You really should do it the other way around and create a view on your SAN target which would only allow access to the LUN you need to  use. This way you would not even have a chance to access the LUNs which are used by other machines.